# how to understand if prometeus exporter agent export metrics on remote machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, javaagents

I am trying to export metrics of an application by using jmx exporter. So basically i added java agent to jvm jmx parameters to run as a agent and configured it to expose localhost:5555. At the end with docker I created container.

So applications runs in remote machine. If it was running on my local I could check localhost:5555/metrics and I could see if metrics are exported. But in my case that apps runs in a container on remote machine. So how can I check if metrics are exported or not ? (Prometheus has not been configured yet so I cannot check on it.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the container is exposing `5555` to a port on its host (let's assume the same port `5555`, i.e. it's running using something of the form `docker run ... --publish=5555:5555 ...`), then, as long as you can access the host machine, you can curl (or browse) the endpoint:

```sh
REMOTE_HOST=...
http://${REMOTE_HOST}:5555/metrics
```